# ExpressJS limiting body size with custom message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my ExpressJS code, I am limiting the body size as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    limit : "512kb",
    extended: false,
    type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}));
```

When the body size exceeds the limit, I want to send back a custom JSON response message. How can I do that?

Comment: i guess you could use a middleware after body parser to check the length in bytes of the response body and either end the request and respond immediately or continue calling `next();` but i'm not sure on how you could check the body length....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add error handler after your bodyparser middleware. Response status will be 413 - Entity Too Large

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#errors

```
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.statusCode === '413')
      return res.send('NOT OK, ENTITY TOO LARGE');
  });
```

Do not forget to check other errors, not only body-parser related

Comment: I know how error handling is done. I want to know specifically that the error was generated due to body parser

Comment: updated code snippet. You can check status code for that entity too large error. Other errors can be checked too, look at the link from answer